# Using an interface, and telling it all implementors _will also_ inherit from a common base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Sometimes, you invent an interface to say that a certain type of object supports a certain type of behavior.  For example, both `Dog` and `ScaryDog` have the `MeleeAttacker` interface.

[image]

But now say I pass a `MeleeAttacker*` into some function,

```
void Attack( MeleeAttacker* attacker, Living *victim ) ;
```

Because `MeleeAttacker` is separated from the hierarchy, I can't access the vitals of `attacker` -- **I cannot access members of `Living` for `attacker` even though I know `attacker` is a `Living`**.  Because of how I constructed the hierarchy, *I know* that `MeleeAttackers` will always be inheritors of the common class `WarmBlooded`.  But the code doesn't know that.  My question is, *how can I tell the code that?*

I think I have just confused things by introducing the `MeleeAttacker` interface, but I didn't want to crowd the base `WarmBlooded` class with functions that won't be implemented in some branches of the hierarchy (for example, the "implementation" for a `Bird`'s melee attack might be `{}` (*nothing*)).

Comment: Why not make the `WarmBlooaded` as virtual base class and let `MeleeAttacker` inherited from it if you know `MeleeAttacker` is always an `WarmBlooded`, Does this works for your case?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply cast your argument to a `Living *` using `dyanmic_cast`? You know it will, since you guarantee that by virtue of your concrete classes implementing the latter whenever the former is implemented.

Basically the idea is kind-of-like `queryInterface` in `COM`, only you don't have to actually implement `queryInterface` yourself in each class, since you know the cast will work, and you don't have to implement graceful handling in your calling code, since, again, you know the cast will succeed.